# docker desktop on macos crashes while building mediasoup demo

Tags: docker

I was wondering what this means: level=error msg="Handler for GET /system/df returned error: error getting build cache usage: failed to get usage for h23kzrlo9o1ntzqg8djaak2ql: snapshot 6p6vktbybxdisl2r4iovhkxaf not found while I'm building this https://github.com/versatica/mediasoup-demo. I get this error on macos when docker desktop on macos crashes. I have big sur on a 2018 macbook pro, a core i7 and 32 gb of ram. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming part of the build process is using Docker containers, you might want to check to be sure Docker for Mac is allowed to use more than the default 2GB memory.  More often than not, that has been the reason Docker crashes on MacOS for me.

Docker -> Preferences -> Resources -> Memory

Increase to 8GB (or more since you have 32GB available).